# Kotlin: Issue implementing interface with getters

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to implement an interface with getter method which matches the constructor parameter name of the implementing class.

```
interface Car{
    fun getModel(): Int
}

class Honda(val model: Int): Car {
    override fun getModel(): Int {

    }
}
```

If `Honda` doesn't implement `getModel()`, we get an `Accidental Override` error. If `Honda` implements `getModel()`, we get a `Platform declaration clash` error.

I can change the name of the parameter in the `Honda` constructor, which fixes the problem, but it feels like a redundant getter method.

```
interface Car{
    fun getModel(): Int
}

class Honda(val modelParam: Int): Car {
    override fun getModel() = modelParam
}
```

Is there a better way to implement such interfaces?

Comment: Probably nothing better than what you have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare [properties in interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html#properties-in-interfaces):

```
interface Car{
    val model : Int
}
```

Then in implementation / constructor you need to add `override` keyword.

```
class Honda(override val model : Int): Car
```

Answer (score 5):

For case where the accepted answer isn't applicable because you can't change the interface, or the interface is a Java one,

```
class Honda(private val model: Int): Car {
    override fun getModel(): Int = model
}
```

For a Java interface, it can still be accessed as `.model` in Kotlin.

Comment: > "it can still be accessed as .model in Kotlin." This does not appear to be the case.